# cant get associative array variables from cookies in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, cookies

i seem to be stuck at this problem for quiet a few time, basically i have used cookie in codeigniter, and passed an array with different names to different functions, the code to set the cookie is

```
$data = array (
            'client_block_ID'  => $client_block_ID,
            'client_unit_ID'   => $client_unit_ID,
            'blockUnits'       => $blockUnits
        );

            $cookieName ='tab'.$counter;

            $cookie = array(
                'name'   => $cookieName,
                'value'  => $data,
                'expire' => '86500',
        );

            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

now i just dont know how to get the variables inside the array i.e what will be the syntax to get client_block_ID??

Comment: $cookie['value']['client_block_ID']; should be enough when cookie is fetched correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now your cookie array will look like this.........

```
$cookie = array(
            'name'   => $cookieName,
            'value'  => array(
                               'client_block_ID'  => $client_block_ID,
                               'client_unit_ID'   => $client_unit_ID,
                               'blockUnits'       => $blockUnits
                        );
            'expire' => '86500',
           );
```

So to get your client_block_ID from your $cookie array you have to loop through that array like below.

```
foreach($cookie as $c)
{
    echo $c['name'];
    foreach($c['value'] as $v)
    {
        echo $v['client_block_ID'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Venkat ?  You do not need loops for that. echo $cookie['value']['client_block_ID']; will be enough in your case of array structure.

Comment: @blogger you can check whether your cookie is there or not using this if(empty($cookie) { echo "NO cookie" } else { do what you want to do }

Comment: sorry for the late replies but i am trying everything possible trying to debug with everything i can get, i am getting the cookie when simple string is passed, but no cookie when array is passed. Maybe there is problem with the syntax of setting the cookie

Answer (score 1):

You did not expect array as value;
I did and I see:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
Filename: core/Input.php
Line Number: 404
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this->input->cookie()
```

> Lets you fetch a cookie. The first parameter will contain the name of the cookie you are looking for (including any prefixes)
>
> The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

try this,

```
 $cookievalue= $this->input->cookie('value');
 if($cookievalue){
   //cookie exists
   foreach($cookievalue as $cookie){
     echo $cookie['client_block_ID'];
   }
}else{
  //cookie doesnot exists
}
```

Comment: so it appears my cookie is not set, maybe it is because of the naming convention i am using, but i tried a similar name, but still nothing!!!

Comment: sorry for the late replies but i am trying everything possible trying to debug with everything i can get, i am getting the cookie when simple string is passed, but no cookie when array is passed. Maybe there is problem with the syntax of setting the cookie